# How to create same database as on local machine on Heroku Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am new to deployment and using herkou for the first time . I have made a PERN app (Postgres , Express, React , Node ). I want to deploy this app to heroku . I have setup the postgres database locally on my machine , but now I want to migrate the same database to postgres - from same I mean same tables & their structures but not the data in the tables.

I don't want to use heroku cli - because I already have lots of cli installed in my machine already . So, Is there a way to upload the database , without writing the whole sql code for creating database and  tables .

I researched alot on this on youtube and google , but didn't find anything helpful .Any help will be appericated.

Thanks in advance